# Regex to add quotes around certain text requirements

Tags: java, javascript, regex, string

I have this string that I am trying to add quotes "" around text that meets certain requirements. The rule is Add "" to the word(s) following 'Text:' and before ';' or '}'
Here is the string: EDIT(notice the "". This is not a JSON Object. Its just a string) :

```
var str = "View_1:{
        Name:"View1";
        Image_1:{
            BackgroundImage:"Image.gif";
            Position: [0, 0];
            Text: 320;
            Height: 480
        },

        Button_1:{
            BackgroundImage:"Button.gif";
            Transition:"View2";
            Position: [49, 80];
            Width: 216;
            Height: 71;
            Text: more text more
        },

        Button_2:{
            BackgroundImage:"Button2.gif";
            Position: [65, 217];
            Width: 188;
            Text:Some Text;
            Height: 134
        },
    }"
```

I cant get it to work

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli The 'var' suggests javascript.

Comment: Also, I don't know what that is, but it's not in JSON syntax. The `;` at the end of the inner most properties is wrong. Really, that's it though, I think.

Comment: The tricky part is that there can be spaces before and after the colon, the word after the colon could already have double or single quotes around it and various characters as content, the part to be quoted could have a newline before the closing curly brace AND some more, probably.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli it is in Javascript. I have been using .replace()

Comment: @JaredFarrish actually this just resembles json(kinda) but its actually something totally different. Its an instruction script for a program we have.

Comment: That's some useful information to have... in the question, that is.

Comment: @Rob Would the string replace work on this custom JSON like structure?

Comment: @JaredFarrish sorry. I tried to make it as to the point as possible. Have a string.. need to add quotes around certain text. Everytime I show a snippet like this people jump to the json resemblance/issues.

Comment: Is the qualified `Text` content prohibited from having breaking whitespace before you get to the next line (and closing `}`? If that's the case, you can setup a simple parser and just feed from that line to the nearest breaking whitespace at the end of the text. And on the JSON thing, I've been working on Symfony lately, and they use YAML. I'm like, why not just JSON? It feels odd.

Comment: @TanzeelKazi Its only an object before I run this replace. At this point its just a string and on its way out of my program. Does your solution below still apply?

Comment: @LeeMeador Yes, there could be spaces. If it could ignore/drop any space between the ':' and the first word and and spaces after the last word and ';'. Hoe that helps

Comment: ... Or, you could go the `Text:` points, drop a quote right after, seek forward to the next `}`, and then backtrack to the next alphanumeric characters and leave a quote at that point. Oh yeah, I suck at regex, so I usually try to find some way to scan or parse it instead.

Comment: @Rob If it's a string and the replace is to be performed in `javascript` it will still apply. If it has to be used in `java` the regex pattern will remain the same but the syntax will change. I think it pretty much covers your replacement needs for this question.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't have quotes around the string definition. Adding those or giving some way to create the string in some language would help. For example, in javascript, if you add a single quote after the equal sign and at the end its still not right because you can't have a multi-line string. java doesn't either.

Comment: @Rob Does Tanzeel's regex work except for the trailing spaces issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/Text:[\s]*([^;}\r\n]+)/ig, 'Text:  "$1"');
```

Though I have my doubts about `str` being a string in your question. It looks more like (an invalid) JSON object than a string.

Comment: maybe the string includes the `var str = ` part...

Comment: Nevermind, I forget that JSON requires double-quoted identifiers, whereas native JS object initializers don't. *That's* what it looks like, minus the `;`.

Comment: Do you want to strip spaces on the end, before the semi-colon, etc? What if there are already double or single quotes?

Comment: @JaredFarrish The `;` is what threw me off. My experience with JSON parsers is that they either parse the entire JSON if it is valid or just spit out an error even if parts of it are invalid.

Comment: @LeeMeador That really depends on if the OP wants to do it. If yes then the regex would change.

Comment: It's got a few other problems... http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/2etcS/

Comment: @LeeMeador there will never be quote already because I originally converted it into an object and stripped extra quotes. I will be using this to add the quotes back.

Comment: @Rob The original question makes no sense once it is an object. It's just a bunch of properties inside an object and the properties have properties. Plus, as was commented, its not valid javascript for defining an object what with the semi-colons.

Comment: @Rob Glad it worked. Though do explain the question content a bit more clearly next time to avoid explosive comments over it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The browser won't be able to interpreting any on this literal javascript object.
There is a syntax error.

You should start by losing the semicolon at every property of your JS object, and adding a simple coma.

It should looks like that:

```
var str = View_1: {
    Name:"View1",
    Image_1:{
        BackgroundImage:"Image.gif",
        Position: [0, 0],
        Text: 320,
        Height: 480
    },

    Button_1:{
        BackgroundImage:"Button.gif";
        Transition:"View2",
        Position: [49, 80],
        Width: 216,
        Height: 71,
        Text: more text more
    },

    Button_2:{
        BackgroundImage:"Button2.gif",
        Position: [65, 217],
        Width: 188,
        Text:Some Text,
        Height: 134
    },
};
```

Semicolon only on the end of your object.
These properties doesn't feel like a regular variable.

Comment: It needs {} around the whole thing, then.

Comment: It's a custom data format, so JSON isn't appropriate unless it were part of pass-through or something.

Comment: I appreciate everyones help, but were over complicating this. Do not think of this as an Object. At this point this is just a String. It and so much more was an object dozens of lines of code before this. Now its just a string and its going to get passed to a C++ program as a String.

Comment: I used this code to add the '_#' numbers to it. 'str = str.replace(/([^:]+):{/g, function(m, p1) {
    i[p1] = (i[p1] || 0)+1;
    return p1 + "_" + i[p1].toString() + ":{";
});'Now im done with them, so I used 'finalString = objString.replace(/_\d+{/g,'{');' to remove them. Now I am trying to add in quotes. make sense?

Comment: @Rob - Can you put that in the question? It's too hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var fixed = s.replace(/(Text:\s*)(.+?)(\s*;|}|$)/gm,'$1"$2"$3');
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/2etcS/1/